# mysql field data types

Tags: php, mysql

i have the following tables: `SUbjects table schema:(id,subject_code)`, and `gradings_level table schema: (id,subject_id,grade,points,marks_range)`. this is for an examination results.
A subject can have many grading levels in this form if marks are out of 100::

```
subject_id marks_range grade points
123        0-30        E     4
123        30-50       D     6
123        50-70       C     7
123        70-80       B     8
123        80-100      A     12
```

that kind of system for all subjects in the database.

my question is?

is it possible for me to store the `marks_range`  in the database so it can be used for each subject or i have to put the logic in a php script

Comment: if marks range is only for reference purpose then as per my idea you can use range as a `string` and store in `varchar` datatype

Answer (score 1):

Store the range in database, but the better variant is to store two `int` columns.

```
marks_range_begin | marks_range_end
```

It's nonsense to make changes in the application when you just want to change makrs range. It's a task for somebody who can manage that in CMS, so, technically, change the value(s) in the database.